# Cannot create a well behind my code

Tags: web

Here is my code so far, basically i'm just trying to create a well behind everything. It will be a single column of content.

```
<div class="well" id="well">
<h1>Aphex Twin</h1>
<h6><em>The genius behind IDM's greatest tracks</em></h6>
<center><a href><img align="middle" src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v669/Baloonda/Webmaster%20stuff/1739519.jpg" width="682.666 height="416"/></a></center>
</div>
```

I don't know what I did wrong. This is all html. I'm not sure if the divs are css properties exclusively? Is there a way to do this with bootstrap? After a couple different tries I still couldn't get it to work. This is my best guess.

sidenote: I'm using http://codepen.io maybe there is a known bug which doesnt allow wells to be made?

Comment: This question is better suited to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ .  SuperUser is geared towards helpdesk and sysadmin questions instead of coding questions (although coding is part of what superusers do).  My suggestion is to keep trying different variations of the code in context with other div's until you see something you like.  Find example pages for inspiration.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage can you delete this and renew my ability to post? (it says only once every 40 minutes) or just move it to webmasters

Comment: I don't have that power, but I have flagged it for someone who does.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage codeasm posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try putting it inside a container

```
<div class="container">... </div>
```

And linked to a bootstrap stylesheet?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If in trouble, try look to here for examples: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_wells.asp

Comment: im not in trouble but that doesn't work either... im using http://codepen.io which automatically adds the style sheets for me.

Comment: did you add a bootstrap css ? the quickadd version 3 or 4 seems to work. (no idea if this link to my example works, but it did for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMZXyW )

Comment: dude you know what? I was using bootstrap 4 in css and bootstrap 3 for JS. It works now.

Comment: It happens to the best of us, good luck on your website writing adventures.